# Xamarin Android : Check if Microsoft Word is installed

Tags: android, xamarin, ms-word, android-package-managers, package-name

I am trying to check programmatically if Microsoft Word (Excel, etc.) from the Playstore is installed on my current device.

I tried to check the installed package with this method:

```
private bool isPackageInstalled(string packagename)
{
    PackageManager pm = Context.PackageManager;
    bool installed = false;
    try
    {
        pm.GetPackageInfo(packagename, PackageInfoFlags.Activities);
        installed = true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        installed = false;
    }
    return installed;
}
```

But I've had no success. I tried ***msword*** and ***application/msword*** as packagenames.

Can someone tell me what are the correct packag enames to check the apps, if the method is not correct, or if there is another, maybe even simpler way to check this?

Comment: did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method seems to be fine, you just need correct package name, for Microsoft Word it's **com.microsoft.office.word**. One easy way to find it is looking online at google play store, it's included in the link:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=**PACKAGE_NAME**
```

for example:

- play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=**com.microsoft.office.word**
- play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=**com.microsoft.office.excel**
- play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=**com.microsoft.office.powerpoint**

Comment: Thanks! The Playstore link hint is very usefull for me! :)